# QtQuick button shows outside of dialog

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols2

I'm trying to make a customizable single button error message dialog in QtQuick, but when I open the dialog the "Ok" button is shown outside of it:

it looks like this

[image]

When I open the dialog again, it works normally, the button is shown at the right place.

Here is a minimal working example :

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

Window {
visible: true
width: 640
height: 480

   Button {
        text: "Open Dialog"
        onClicked: {
            dialog.show("This text can be customized.")
      }

    Dialog {

        id: dialog
        standardButtons: Dialog.Ok
        title: "Error"
        modal: true

        function show(txt) {
            label.text = txt
            open()
        }

        Label {
            id: label
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using Qt 5.11.3 with QtQuick 2.11, build target is Desktop GCC 64 bits.

Is this a bug? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does your example reproduce the error? because the button looks fine for me!

Comment: Oh that is weird. I've just created a new  "Qt Quick application - Empty" in QtCreator, pasted the example in main.qml, and the bug is there. I'm running the app on Linux though. I also tested on Android, the bug is there as well. On which OS did you test @luffy ?

Comment: Also, this only happens in Qt 5.11.3, I've just tried out in Qt 5.14, the bug isn't there (with the same version of QtQuick and QtQuick.Controls!)

Comment: I tested on Windows 10. I will try to test it on Linux. I have Ubuntu 18 running in a VM

Comment: what a meaning of the `Item` inside `Window`? this element doesn't make any sense here, moreover since it has no size it can cause to incorrect positioning of the nested items. Also the `Button` should be at (0,0) since you don't define any position for it. Therefore, it looks that your sample code does not match the image you provided.

Comment: The Item is indeed useless, I've removed it, but it doesn't change anything. Also, the Button is indeed at (0,0), it is the button to spawn the Dialog. Then the dialog spawns at (0,0) because it has no coordinates defined. But the wrongly placed button is the Ok button of the Dialog, generated by "standardButtons: Dialog.Ok" @folibis

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in Qt 5.11.3 or in my installation of it on Linux.

Here is the workaround I used, basically recreating the Dialog from a regular Popup :

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Popup {
    x: (parent.width-width)/2
    y: (parent.height-height)/2
    modal: true
    closePolicy: Popup.NoAutoClose

    property var title: "Error"
    property var msg: ""

    function show(message) {
        msg = message
        open()
    }

    ColumnLayout {
        spacing: 30

        Label {
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
            Layout.preferredHeight: 5

            font.bold: true
            text: title

        }

        Label {
           text: msg
        }

        Button {
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight
            text: "Ok"
            onClicked: {
                close()
            }
        }

    }
}
```